# Spring Batch: RowMapper is not getting Autowuired

Tags: spring-batch

I have this configuration:

```
<bean id="reader" class="com.company.MyReader" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="select * from dummy"/>
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowMapper"/>
    <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rowMapper" class="com.company.MyRowMapper>
    <property name="firstName" value="hillary/>
</bean>
```

MyRowMapper implements **org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper**

MyReader extends **org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader**

Within MyReader, **super.doRead()** is called, and this returns MyRowMapper objects.
However, these objects are not  getting autowired by the container - the property firstName comes back as null. Note that MyReader is being autowired by the Spring container as expected.

What needs to be done so that RowMapper is autowired?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you share your MyRowMapper source?

Answer (score 1):

Have you annotated MyReader to notify Spring that it needs instance of MyRowMapper?

```
     public class com.company.MyReader{

        @Autowired
        private MyRowMapper mapper;


        public void setMyRowMapper(MyRowMapper newMapper){
            this.mapper = newMapper;
        }
    }
```